# Как из Json вытащить значение кода города?

Tags: php, json, api

Есть код

```
<?php

$map = function($array, $from, $to){
    $result = [];
    if(!empty($array) && is_array($array)){
        foreach ($array as $element) {
            $key = $element[$from]?:null;
            $value = $element[$to]?:null;
            if($key && $value){
                $result[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
};

$airlines = $map(json_decode(file_get_contents('http://aviaciya.com/json/airlines.json'), true), 'iata', 'name');
$cit=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://aviaciya.com/json/cities.json")); $cities=array(); foreach($cit as $val) { if(property_exists($val->name_translations,"ru")) $cities[$val->code]=$val->name_translations->ru;}


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=MOW&destination=-&token=*******");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: ********"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$products=json_decode($response,true);




$replace_value = function($key, $val) use ($cities, $airlines){
    $response = $val;
    switch($key){case 'destination':
            $response = $cities[$val];break;
            case 'origin':
            $response = $cities[$val];break;
        case 'airline':
            $response = $airlines[$val];
            break;
    }
    return $response;
}

?>
<table class="features-table">
<thead style="background: rgba(2, 69, 141, 0.46) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <tr>
              <th class="views-field views-field-field-logo-fid">
        Пункт отправления     </th>
              <th class="views-field views-field-tid">
          Пункт назначения      </th>
          <th class="views-field views-field-tid-1">
  Авиакомпания       </th>
              <th class="views-field views-field-tid-1">
  Цена, р.        </th>

              <th class="views-field views-field-field-cenaot-value">
         Дата вылета     </th>

              <th class="views-field views-field-field-prodsgapo-value">Обратная дата
             </th>
              <th class="views-field views-field-field-perelets-value"></th>

             </tr>
  </thead>

<?php
if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])) {
foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {
foreach ($data as $destination => $row) {
if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}/i', $key)) {
?>
<tr><td><?php echo Москва;?></td>
    <td><?= $replace_value('destination',$key) ? $replace_value('destination', $key) : "<b>" .'Обновл.'. "</b>"; ?></a></td>
       <td><span class="title"><img height="50" width="120" src="http://pics.avs.io/180/70/<?= $row['airline']?>.png" /></span></td>
<td><?php echo $replace_value('price', $row['price']); ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo $replace_value('departure_at', substr($row['departure_at'], 0, 10)); ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo $replace_value('return_at', substr($row['return_at'], 0, 10)); ?></a></td>
<td><a rel="nofollow" alt="авиабилеты Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?>" title="авиабилеты Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?>" href="http://avia.aviaciya.com/searches/new?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=<?=$key?>&depart_date=<?=substr($row['departure_at'], 0, 10)?>&return_date=<?=substr($row['return_at'], 0, 10)?>&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true">Поиск</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Есть ответ:

```
{"success": true, "data": {"AAH":{"1":{"price":17420,"airline":"KL","flight_number":904,"departure_at":"2017-04-17T17:00:00Z","return_at":"2017-04-25T15:15:00Z","expires_at":"2016-11-30T11:36:28Z"}
```

Из этого ответа мне нужно вывести вот это "AAH" в исходном виде P.s/ В ответе много таких значений. Заранее спасибо

Comment: вы же умеете работать с массивами?
json_decode(строка, true) и у вас массив. А если умеете работать с объектами то можно и без true;

Comment: binliz, не умею, мне достался код в таком виде, он переводит код города в нормальный человеческий вид, но мне нужно вот в эту строчку     <td><span class="title"><img height="50" width="120" src="http://pics.avs.io/180/70/<?= $row['airline']?>.png" /></span></td> чтобы заместо кода аэропорта вставлялся код города, в том виде в который в ответе Json

Comment: **foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) ** у вас проход по ключам и по рассписаниям. Так вот в $key как раз содержится AAH

Comment: binliz , пробовал вот так <img height="50" width="120" src="http://pics.avs.io/180/70/<?= $key['destination']?>.jpg" /> не получается

Comment: $key у вас AAH это не массив а ключ потому  $key['destination'] скорее всего null вам надо вписать именно $key

Comment: Вот так <?= echo $key ?>?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49324/discussion-between-binliz-and-arcadiy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорить именно о картинке то,

```
http://pics.avs.io/180/70/<?= $row['airline']?>.png
```

надо заменить `**$row['airline']**` на `$key`

Comment: Спасибо огромное